# Checking for visibility of image files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I've recently been asked to create a page that handles image file uploads to the server using ajax and php. The catch is when the file is selected, it should be previewed on the page.

The problem is my eyes are destroyed therefore I cannot validate the image if it is visible or not to the user. To solve, I ended up checking the src attribute for the value, like this:

```
$("#img").attr('src');
```

My question is: Given a certain length and height to the  element, will I be certain that as long as the src attribute has a value, a valid image file will be visible? Will it work in all cases? If not, what is the best way to check if the image exists and is visible?

Comment: Your question is not fully clear for me. What do you want to do and what do you really want to check?

Comment: @eisbehr suppose I create an <img> element in a page containing an image file, what is the best way to know if the image is loaded successfully in the page and is visible to the user?

Comment: check the onload event fired on that IMG-element.

Comment: Okay, I can provide you a check for the loading. But what do **you** mean by `visible to the user`? Just to be sure. Do you men it is in the viewport? Or do you mean he clicked somewhere? ...

Comment: @eisbehr literally "visible". If you load an image and somehow you can't see the image in the page. Suppose you can't see the screen, how would you check for the visibility of the image programmatically? I am currently relying on the src attribute. I believe if the src attribute has a value, it means the image is successfully loaded and is visible to the user. Is this true in all cases?

Comment: Read about HTMLImageElement.complete @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement - it may return true if src is empty .. but both together should work. Maybe ask a sighted person to confirm testing code you provide.

Comment: @morbidcode - no - the src being non-empty does not mean it has loaded successfully - imagine a reference to a non-existing file.

Comment: @flowtron "ask a sighted person" - so this is impossible without sighted asistance?

Comment: during development, .. I guess you'll need to have it confirmed. but then the code should work. In other words - write us up a small jsfiddle and then we can say "yes, it works - we see the image"

Comment: @flowtron I guess being able to check if the image load successfully would be fine. I'll leave the problem of positioning it for better user experience to others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the loading state and availability of an image you can use `load` and `error` event listener.

```
$("#img").on("load", function() {
    // the image is successfully loaded
}).on("error", function() {
    // the image could not be loaded, maybe the image is not availbale
});
```

Comment: If I understood correctly the viewport issue is not what the question is about

Comment: In the comment he wrote: `and is visible to the user`. You can only check this with the viewport. Other things like `:visible` will only check the visibility in the page, but not if the user *saw* the image. But he can correct me, then I change the answer ... @flowtron

Comment: Yes, but you see the issue here is that the developer lacks the ability to personally confirm visibility and wants to find a programmatic way to ensure he can confirm the image has been successfully uploaded.

Comment: But if he combined the callbacks and checks, you can do it with this. Or not? Please give me an hint, if you have an other understanding of the question or a better idea. I will update my answer then. But actually this would be my best idea ...

Comment: @eisbehr can you explain more on what this viewport means? Also I don't understand visible to the page vs visible to the user. Aren't they the same?

Comment: the viewport may only be a section of the page - if you've scrolled down (enough) you're no longer seeing the image(s) at the top.

Comment: Viewport means `in the screen`. Imagine a page with a scrollbar on the right. There may be content the user currently don't see, but it is on the page below. So the user hasn't saw the image yet, but it would be there. Visible on the page only means, it is *there* but probably not seen by anyone yet. @morbidCode

Comment: @flowtron you mean in order to validate the image I have to put that inside this viewport?

Comment: Maybe not. But actually we're a bit confused by what `validate` means for you. @morbidCode

Comment: @eisbehr sorry but I'm getting a little bit confused. What if I did this <img src="file.jpg"> anywhere on the page, will the position of the line of code determine if the user can see the image even if it's already visible in the page?

Comment: If you use the `load` callback, you would actually know that the image is there on the server and could be used anywhere. Isn't that the thing you want to know? What would you like to know anymore? @morbidCode

Comment: If you have a page with a lot of content and the image would be at the bottom, the user has to scroll to the image first, to see the image. Otherwise the image would be out of the viewport. That is what my code checks. The opposide would be, to check if the image is visible on the page, but not if the user saw the image. That is a difference. @morbidCode

Comment: @eisbehr I think I understand now. I am unclear, the only thing I need is for the image to be visible on the page. I believe other developers would not find it hard to position that image as long as it's loaded correctly right?

Comment: Than you don't need any visibility check. Juse use the `load` callback. If the image is loaded, you can use it anywhere. I will remove the visbility check from my answer. @morbidCode